# java.io.FileNotFoundException: .. (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, linux, windows, filenotfoundexception

I had developed a Java project correctly working on Eclipse under Windows OS. Then I wanted to switch to Ubuntu. I just took the full workspace folder (included all resources file required for the running) from Windows and imported it in the Ubuntu's Eclipse.

Most surprisingly I get the following exception:

```
[ Test ] ERROR: unable to create myClass object. 
Check your implementation requirements!
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at Test.main(Test.java:183)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: raw\file1.txt (No such file or directory)
...
```

but such directory and such file do actually exist in the current path.

Why may this happen?

Comment: While Windows may accept backslashes as path separators, Unix does not. Use a forward slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a forward slash, '/', as it's the one that will work in file paths for both Windows and non-Windows platforms.

Answer (score 8):

Use `File.separator` instead of `"/"` in any project.

Comment: I would say "in any project".

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg True enough, should have said that.